# How can I activate the Tensorboard in pycharm without Anaconda environment?

Tags: pycharm, tensorboard

I install the pycharm and tensorflow-gpu without Anaconda.
And now I want to use the TensorBoard, how can I activate it without Anaconda environment.
Thanks all answers I will get.
Good luck to all of you.